# CSS Code for eras light itc

Tags: css

can anyone give the css coding for "eras light ITC" font. I am unable to get it. The coding is

```
.para-quote {
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100; }
```

I want eras light ITC instead of sans-serif. Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: font-family: "eras light itc";

Comment: Sorry this one : font-family: "eras light itc"; forgot the quotes

Comment: tried that too but not working, should I incude any font-face?

Comment: you need not include font-face.. check my answer.. it differs as per the browser.. so include {font-family: "Eras ITC", "Eras Light ITC",  sans-serif ;}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in the way different browsers interpret fonts for example

Firefox allows the use of "Eras ITC",

Chrome wants you to pick one of the variations of Eras, as in "medium", "bold", etc. but won't let your just use "Eras ITC".

IE9 doesn't care and will render all fonts installed on your windows system (you can check just by typing "fonts" in your start menu and picking installed fonts.)

Opera seems to work similar to IE9 as far as using system fonts

here is the answer that works:

```
{font-family: "Eras ITC", "Eras Light ITC",  sans-serif ;}
```

This will work in all browsers, at least on windows systems... sans-serif is just kind of a fall back for any failure with the first two fonts.

Comment: Glad to help :) it all depends on the browser :)