# Font works in IE, but but not Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am having problem with fonts displaying in a website I am making. I am using the font ErasITC Light. The relevant HTML is:

```
<div class="heading">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>make your voice heard</h1>
    <h2>it's time to let the people speak out</h2>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS is:

```
.heading h1{
font-family: ErasITC, Eras Light ITC, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 6.25vw;
font-weight: 300;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 15px black;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 21vh;

}

.heading h2{
    font-family: ErasITC, Eras Light ITC, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2.7vw;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This works in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox, where it displays a default Sans-Serif font.

NOTE: I am using bootstrap for some elements.

Thanks,

Geffen Avraham.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608504/css-code-for-eras-light-itc

Comment: {font-family: "Eras ITC", "Eras Light ITC",  sans-serif ;}?

Comment: Do you declare your font as a `@font-face`? Can you post the code?

Comment: The answer is already given by one of the Member . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608504/css-code-for-eras-light-itc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using white-spaces for font names you have to put them in quotes, like so:

```
font-family: "Eras ITC", "Eras Light ITC", Sans-Serif;
```

Comment: double quote is missing, it should be like  {font-family: "Eras ITC", "Eras Light ITC",  sans-serif ;}

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I had seen the question you directed me to, but had not noticed the quotations. Do you know why internet explorer correctly displayed the fonts, even though I had not programmed it right?