# Asp.net webpage is not displayed correctly in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

The webpage is displayed correctly in IE or Microsoft Edge but not in Chrome or Firefox.The controls are misplaced and even the styled fonts are not display correctly.

here is a sample of my code:

```
<asp:Label ID="schoolHead" runat="server" Text="WELCOME HOME" AssociatedControlID="schoolHead" style="position:absolute; top: 66px; left: 1160px; font-size:80px; font-family:Eras Bold ITC" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font works in IE, but but not Firefox or Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820478/font-works-in-ie-but-but-not-firefox-or-chrome)

Comment: Need more info for this post to be helpful.  Can you provide a link to the site, or more code to reproduce the error?