# Browsers not honoring fonts in bootstrap

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a basic [Bootstrap starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) in order to experiment with the various bootswatch themes available. I noticed that when I would change my bootswatch theme (e.g., from "cerulean" to "yeti") that while the colors specified in the theme's css were being changed in the browser, the fonts were *not* changing in Firefox (update 53) or Chrome (ver 59); however, IE 11 does show the proper font. No matter what bootswatch theme I choose, the fonts in the theme's css are only being honored in IE.

My search for answers so far has come up short. I have referenced the question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608504/css-code-for-eras-light-itc", but I'm not sure if this is what I'm up against or whether it's something else in my way.

Comment: The font in question is "Open Sans", being applied to the <body> by bootstrap.css:
body {
   font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Google Fonts to render Open Sans or is it the font for your Bootswatch Theme? If you're rendering via Google Fonts, make sure that your link to it comes AFTER your bootstrap.css files.

Also: if you're working with a live site make sure that you're not getting stymied by the site's cache (which can cause delays in the changes to a .css file displaying).

Comment: Huh? The font files must be loaded before the stylesheet that references it. You got it the wrong way around.

Comment: Whoops! You're correct, I typed that out in reverse.

Comment: The fonts are in my Bootswatch theme. My first css link is for Bootstrap ('lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') and the second link is for the Bootswatch theme css ('lib/bootswatch/yeti/bootstrap.min.css'). The site is in dev, not prod.

Comment: AFAIK, the Bootswatch themes are standalone and if you try and run both the Bootstrap 3 and Bootswatch theme you'll run into problems like this.

Try to comment out your bootstrap CDN and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Commenting out the bootstrap CDN results in the same behavior. I'm fairly certain Bootstrap requires a reference to the Bootstrap core css followed by a reference to the custom Bootswatch style/template css you want to use.

Comment: Bootswatch documentation states that you should replace the Bootstrap CSS with the Bootswatch CSS. 

**https://bootswatch.com/help/**:
_Using the themes is as easy as downloading a CSS file and replacing the one that comes with Bootstrap._

I don't believe they're meant to run together.

Comment: After further reading & experimenting, the problem was that I did not have Open Sans on my system and nothing at the top of my page to download the font if needed. I linked it to Google fonts with: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"/>'

Answer (score 0):

The Bootswatch template and the core Bootstrap css were making a reference to the font "Open Sans", but the font was not a font on the system. It needed to be downloaded from the Google web font library at the top of the page with: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"/>`. Once that was done, the page loaded according to the Bootswatch template, honoring both the colors and the fonts.